tanstack table: how to expand and show various data in a row and not trigger all expandable action button in same row onClick action button
I want each action button will have it's own expandable independent row. I'm halfway there. I'm using tanstack table v8. But the problem is, if I click on any expandable button in a row that trigger all expandable buttons in the same row. I don't want that. Each action will trigger on it's own and expand a row with new data.
Is it possible with tanstack table  or any other way?
Whatever I've tried so far is in this codesandbox.
App.tsx
import {
  ColumnDef,
  ColumnFiltersState,
  SortingState,
  VisibilityState,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getExpandedRowModel,
  getFacetedRowModel,
  getFacetedUniqueValues,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useState } from "react";

import { expandableColumn, expandableData } from "./column-data";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
  renderSubComponent: (props: { row: Row<TData> }) => React.ReactElement;
  getRowCanExpand: (row: Row<TData>) => boolean;
}

const renderSubComponent = ({ row }: { row: Row<Person> }) => {
  return (
    <pre style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(row.original, null, 2)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
};

export function ExpandableTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  renderSubComponent,
  getRowCanExpand,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getRowCanExpand,
    state: {
      columnVisibility,
    },
    autoResetPageIndex: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    <div className="space-y-4">
      {/* <AnchorTableToolbar table={table} /> */}
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <table>
          <thead>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <th key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </th>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <>
                  <tr
                    key={row.id}
                    data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                  >
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                      <td key={cell.id}>
                        {flexRender(
                          cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                          cell.getContext()
                        )}
                      </td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>

                  {row.getIsExpanded() && (
                    <tr>
                      {/* 2nd row is a custom 1 cell row */}
                      <td colSpan={row.getVisibleCells().length}>
                        {renderSubComponent({ row })}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )}
                </>
              ))
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
                  No results.
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Expand Table Example</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ExpandableTable
        data={expandableData}
        columns={expandableColumn}
        renderSubComponent={renderSubComponent}
        getRowCanExpand={() => true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

column.tsx
export const expandableColumn = [
  {
    accessorKey: "firstName",
    header: "First Name",
    cell: ({ row, getValue }) => (
      <div
        style={{
          // Since rows are flattened by default,
          // we can use the row.depth property
          // and paddingLeft to visually indicate the depth
          // of the row
          paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
        }}
      >
        {row.getCanExpand() ? (
          <button
            {...{
              onClick: row.getToggleExpandedHandler(),
              style: { cursor: "pointer" },
            }}
          >
            {row.getIsExpanded() ? "" : ""}
          </button>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {getValue<string>()}
      </div>
    ),
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
  {
    accessorFn: (row) => row.lastName,
    id: "lastName",
    cell: ({ row, getValue }) => (
      <div
        style={{
          // Since rows are flattened by default,
          // we can use the row.depth property
          // and paddingLeft to visually indicate the depth
          // of the row
          paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
        }}
      >
        {row.getCanExpand() ? (
          <button
            {...{
              onClick: row.getToggleExpandedHandler(),
              style: { cursor: "pointer" },
            }}
          >
            {row.getIsExpanded() ? "♟" : ""}
          </button>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {getValue<string>()}
      </div>
    ),
    header: () => <span>Last Name</span>,
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "age",
    header: () => "Age",
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "visits",
    header: () => <span>Visits</span>,
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "status",
    header: "Status",
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "progress",
    header: "Profile Progress",
    footer: (props) => props.column.id,
  },
];

export const expandableData = [
  {
    firstName: "Marquis",
    lastName: "Runolfsdottir",
    age: 36,
    visits: 322,
    progress: 46,
    status: "single",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Hayden",
    lastName: "Ritchie",
    age: 35,
    visits: 208,
    progress: 79,
    status: "relationship",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Destany",
    lastName: "Boehm",
    age: 37,
    visits: 752,
    progress: 97,
    status: "relationship",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kale",
    lastName: "Johnston",
    age: 36,
    visits: 378,
    progress: 13,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Maybell",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: 16,
    visits: 783,
    progress: 76,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Emelia",
    lastName: "Cronin",
    age: 30,
    visits: 655,
    progress: 96,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kali",
    lastName: "Marvin",
    age: 18,
    visits: 926,
    progress: 57,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Khalid",
    lastName: "Robel",
    age: 34,
    visits: 671,
    progress: 100,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zena",
    lastName: "Hilll",
    age: 34,
    visits: 934,
    progress: 18,
    status: "single",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Hiram",
    lastName: "Koss",
    age: 12,
    visits: 757,
    progress: 44,
    status: "relationship",
  },
];



I have never used Tanstack... After a quick look in the docs it doesn't seem that it supports multiple expanded stuff.
I handled it manually: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/goofy-shtern-forked-3kny3x
Basically the idea is to have a state that will control how the rows/cells are expanded. The expandedRowState does that, it saves the id of the row, which column is expanded and the expanded content. And when clicking to expand, instead of just expanding, I did some checks using the column.
App.tsx
import "./styles.css";
import {
  ColumnDef,
  VisibilityState,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getExpandedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { useState } from "react";

import { expandableColumns, expandableData } from "./column-data";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
  expandedRowContent: any;
  getRowCanExpand: (row: any) => boolean;
}

export function ExpandableTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  expandedRowContent,
  getRowCanExpand,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getRowCanExpand,
    state: {
      columnVisibility,
    },
    autoResetPageIndex: false,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    <div className="space-y-4">
      <div className="rounded-md border">
        <table>
          <thead>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <th key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </th>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <>
                  <tr
                    key={row.id}
                    data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                  >
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                      <td key={cell.id}>
                        {flexRender(
                          cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                          cell.getContext()
                        )}
                      </td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>

                  {row.getIsExpanded() && (
                    <tr>
                      {/* 2nd row is a custom 1 cell row */}
                      <td colSpan={row.getVisibleCells().length}>
                        {expandedRowContent[row.id].content}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )}
                </>
              ))
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
                  No results.
                </td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [expandedRowState, setExpandedRowState] = useState<any>([]);

  const setExpandedRowStateById = (id: any, content: any, columnIndex: any) => {
    expandedRowState[id] = { content, columnIndex };
    setExpandedRowState([...expandedRowState]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Expand Table Example</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ExpandableTable
        data={expandableData}
        columns={expandableColumns(expandedRowState, setExpandedRowStateById)}
        expandedRowContent={expandedRowState}
        getRowCanExpand={() => true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

column-data.tsx
export const expandableColumns = (expandedRowState: any, setExpandedRowState: any) => {
  return [
    {
      accessorKey: "firstName",
      header: "First Name",
      cell: ({ row, getValue }: any) => (
        <div
          style={{
            paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
          }}
        >
          {row.getCanExpand() ? (
            <button
              {...{
                onClick: () => {
                  if (!row.getIsExpanded() || (row.getIsExpanded() && expandedRowState[row.id].columnIndex == 0)) {
                    row.getToggleExpandedHandler()();
                  }

                  setExpandedRowState(row.id, <p>FINGER EMOJI - {row.original.firstName}</p>, 0);
                },
                style: { cursor: "pointer" },
              }}
            >
              {row.getIsExpanded() && expandedRowState[row.id].columnIndex == 0 ? "" : ""}
            </button>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          {getValue()}
        </div>
      ),
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorFn: (row: { lastName: any }) => row.lastName,
      id: "lastName",
      cell: ({ row, getValue }: any) => (
        <div
          style={{
            paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
          }}
        >
          {row.getCanExpand() ? (
            <button
              {...{
                onClick: () => {
                  if (!row.getIsExpanded() || (row.getIsExpanded() && expandedRowState[row.id].columnIndex == 1)) {
                    row.getToggleExpandedHandler()();
                  }

                  setExpandedRowState(row.id, <p>FLASHLIGHT EMOJI - {row.original.lastName}</p>, 1);
                },
                style: { cursor: "pointer" },
              }}
            >
              {row.getIsExpanded() && expandedRowState[row.id].columnIndex == 1 ? "♟" : ""}
            </button>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          {getValue()}
        </div>
      ),
      header: () => <span>Last Name</span>,
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "age",
      header: () => "Age",
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "visits",
      header: () => <span>Visits</span>,
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "status",
      header: "Status",
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "progress",
      header: "Profile Progress",
      footer: (props: { column: { id: any } }) => props.column.id,
    },
  ];
};

export const expandableData = [
  {
    firstName: "Marquis",
    lastName: "Runolfsdottir",
    age: 36,
    visits: 322,
    progress: 46,
    status: "single",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Hayden",
    lastName: "Ritchie",
    age: 35,
    visits: 208,
    progress: 79,
    status: "relationship",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Destany",
    lastName: "Boehm",
    age: 37,
    visits: 752,
    progress: 97,
    status: "relationship",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kale",
    lastName: "Johnston",
    age: 36,
    visits: 378,
    progress: 13,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Maybell",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: 16,
    visits: 783,
    progress: 76,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Emelia",
    lastName: "Cronin",
    age: 30,
    visits: 655,
    progress: 96,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kali",
    lastName: "Marvin",
    age: 18,
    visits: 926,
    progress: 57,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Khalid",
    lastName: "Robel",
    age: 34,
    visits: 671,
    progress: 100,
    status: "complicated",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Zena",
    lastName: "Hilll",
    age: 34,
    visits: 934,
    progress: 18,
    status: "single",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Hiram",
    lastName: "Koss",
    age: 12,
    visits: 757,
    progress: 44,
    status: "relationship",
  },
];


Thank your for your solution. Your solution works. But the problem, I'm going to use this table in my production app. That's why I'm not sure how much optimized or standard your solution is! But again, thank you so much for your solution.
If you can come up with more better solution please answer.

No problems, I understand. Maybe if you change your approach, it would be easier. Because usually when you expand, you are expanding the row, so the most common is to have only 1 expand action, as you want multiple actions, maybe show a modal instead of expand the row?

That is actually a very good idea. I already used modal in my other tables. But, In this particular table the table row should be expandable.

This works. Thanks

I created whole new  functionality for expanding single cell using tanstack table's super powerful and amazing feature called Custom Feature Guide. This feature is intruduced in version 8.14.0.
You can learn more from hrere https://tanstack.com/table/latest/docs/guide/custom-features#:~:text=TanStack%20Table%20has%20a%20core,more%20features%20to%20the%20library.
